# What are my responsibilities with regards to reporting suspected Fraud?

Tags: professionalism, colleagues, united-kingdom

I work in a school in the UK. I work as part of a 3 man in house I.T. team employed directly by the school. There is my boss me and another tech.  We are all contracted to work 37 hours and overtime as needed.  I think both the people I work with are reporting more hours than they are actually working.  I am not certain what I should do since the person I would normally report these suspicions to (my boss) is one of the people I believe is over reporting their hours.

What are my obligations here? Can I be disciplined or worse for ignoring it should the truth come out?  What should I be doing to protect myself.

Comment: Welcome to the public sector.

Comment: Simple question: do you have proof?

Comment: have you talked to them about all the "homework" they do?

Comment: @MrFox - I can't believe you recieved 6 upvotes for that comment.  Every single person I work with works more hours then they get paid for.  Most public-sector employees are honest working people.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm sorry that the comment offended you. It's a light-hearted joke at the (much higher!) job security of unionized public workers vs. the industry. I've known people in the public sector who could do no wrong and had no shame about abusing the situation. That being said, I'm sure there are good people and bad people in every sector.

Answer (score 1):

Your *obligations* begin with **yourself**. Be sure that you are accurately reporting your hours.

Regarding your **peers**, your responsibility is to hold them accountable for their particular projects. This is especially true for any projects that impact you or are shared. Beyond that, you as their peer are not responsible for holding them accountable for their reported hours (I am assuming you don't approve their time.).

Regarding your **boss**, this is really none of your concern, unless it is impacting your work. This could be in the form of not getting accurate or timely information. If this or something similar is the case, then you should address that particular issue with your boss.

[Many workplaces are shifting to more flexible working environments](http://www.americanprogress.org/wp-content/uploads/issues/2012/08/pdf/flexibility_factsheet.pdf), including everything from working different hours to working from home. This does not alter any performance expectations for individuals or teams. Everyone should be held to the same standards, which revolve around what they produce, not when they clock in and out.